# jquery $.parseJSON(data); method is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

The parse method is not working.

```
$.get("viewsGroup.process", function(data) {
    $("#view_group").modal("show");
    alert(data);                  // this shows the no of objects..
    var data = $.ParseJSON(data); // not working ....
    alert("datata" + data);       // not working..
    console.log(data.name);
    alert("bacjkkkk");
});
```

Comment: The last argument for $.get is the dataType, just set that and jQuery does this for you

Comment: you could also just use `$.getJSON("url", function(d){ //stuff here })`.

Comment: It's difficult to help you if you just say "not working". This doesn't really give us any idea about what the problem could be. [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), and maybe you can help yourself.

Comment: Felix Kling sir...problem is that...$.get("viewsGroup.process", function(data) //data is json String of type(jsonArrray)  this (data) String have a list as a object....i want to convert it Using $.parseJSON(data)//this is not working not converting it...after converstion i want to use (each) loop to show the all objects that data one by one using loop (each).//it is not converting from json thats why the rest of work i cannot do...

Comment: Again, what does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? Don't you get the output you expect? What is the result of `$.parseJSON(data)`?

Comment: donot get the result...no eroor ..

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

`$.ParseJSON(data);` should be  `$.parseJSON(data);`

Hoping this will help.

Comment: i know that is $.parseJSON(data);//but problem is that..data is list type jsonArray String..and my code is not working after that point where i am pasrsing the json string (data).

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the code as such:

```
$.getJSON("viewsGroup.process", function (d) {
    $("#view_group").modal("show");
    console.log(d);

    //whatever else you want to do

})
```

Comment: thanks for reply bt i wana parse this (d)...and parse method is not working ...thats problem,,,